# Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Droppa\DroppaShipping\Model\Carrier\DroppaShipping does not exist

Tags: magento2, php-7

I am new on the Magento 2 eCommerce platform and I have created my own shipping model. On the Admin configuration sales page, all the contents appears just fine, the problem is the Front side view, I am getting this error below:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Droppa\DroppaShipping\Model\Carrier\DroppaShipping does not exist
```

Please see attached Google Drive link to see the full error:
[https://drive.google.com/file/d/10bB3_I6SrG73o822I-ksXpzgPjreF2l2/view?usp=sharing][1]

This is how made the config.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <carriers>
            <droppashipping>
                <specificerrmsg>This shipping method is not available. To use this shipping method, please contact us.</specificerrmsg>
                <active>0</active>
                <name>Droppa Shipping</name>
                <title>Droppa Shipping Method</title>
                <price>175.00</price>
                <handling_type>F</handling_type>
                <shipping_cost>10</shipping_cost>
                <sallowspecific>0</sallowspecific>
                <sort_order>15</sort_order>
                <min_package_weight>1</min_package_weight>
                <max_package_weight>30</max_package_weight>
                <model>Droppa\DroppaShipping\Model\Carrier\DroppaShipping</model>
            </droppashipping>
        </carriers>
    </default>
</config>
```

This is the Model\Carrier\DroppaShipping Object

```
namespace Droppa\DroppaShipping\Model\Carrier;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrier;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\CarrierInterface;


if (!class_exists('DroppaShipping')) {

    class DroppaShipping extends AbstractCarrier implements CarrierInterface
    {
        protected $_code = 'droppashipping';
        protected $_rateResultFactory;
        protected $_rateMethodFactory;
        protected $_isFixed = true;

        /**
         * Shipping constructor.
         *
         * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface          $scopeConfig
         * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory  $rateErrorFactory
         * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface                                    $logger
         * @param \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory                  $rateResultFactory
         * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory
         * @param array                                                       $data
         */
        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
            \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory,
            \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
            \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateResultFactory,
            \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory,
            array $data = []
        ) {
            $this->_rateResultFactory = $rateResultFactory;
            $this->_rateMethodFactory = $rateMethodFactory;
            parent::__construct($scopeConfig, $rateErrorFactory, $logger, $data);
        }

        /**
         * get allowed methods
         * @return array
         */
        public function getAllowedMethods()
        {
            # Retrieve information from carrier configuration
            return [$this->_code => $this->getConfigData('name')];
        }
        /**
         * @return float
         */
        private function getShippingPrice()
        {
            $configPrice = $this->getConfigData('price');
            return $this->getFinalPriceWithHandlingFee($configPrice);
        }
        /**
         * @param RateRequest $request
         * @return bool|Result
         */
        public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
        {
            if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
                return false;
            }

            /** @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result $result (module-shipping Shipping) */
            $result = $this->_rateResultFactory->create();

            /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method $method */
            $method = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create();

            /**Method overwritten */
            $method->setCarrier($this->_code);
            $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

            $method->setMethod($this->_code);
            $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));

            # $shippingCost = (float)$this->getConfigData('shipping_cost');

            $amount = $this->getShippingPrice();

            $method->setPrice($amount);
            $method->setCost($amount);

            $result->append($method);

            // var_dump($request->getOrigCity(), $request->getOrigPostcode(), $request->getDestPostcode(), $request->getPackageWeight(), $request->getPackageWidth(), $request->getPackageHeight());

            return $result;
        }
    }
}
```

I have ran the [**php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f**] command and also [**php bin/magento setup:upgrade**] to update my database. I am not really sure where I've went wrong or which step I've missed.

Answer (score 0):

The class isn't found so it could be a few things.

Here's a few things to check / keep in mind:

1. The error mentions reflection and that means Magento 2 is investigating the class and its dependencies.
   Did you run `bin/magento setup:di:compile`?
   This command regenerates the php classes with constructor dependencies and makes Interceptors for classes so plugins can do their thing. Redeploying static files seem irrelevant here.
   If your generated files aren't up to date the type hinting in a constructor may resolve to some wrong namespace. This happens if you change a namespace or constructor or path without running the compile command.
   In this case the namespace in the error and the class do seem to be correct.
2. Did you enable the module? Use `bin/magento module:status` to see and `bin/magento module:enable Droppa_DroppaShipping` to enable it.
3. Did you disable or flush caching for compiled configuration and cache for data collections? XML confuguration like that gets merged and cached. Magento does try to use the class so it's probably not it.
4. It doesn't complain about a file missing. Just about a class missing. That also happens when a file gets loaded but it doesn't contain a class with the right classname or namespace. As far as I can see it's not the actual issue here, but it's wise to keep it in mind.
5. It could be an autoload issue. In what path did you put your module?
   Are other files loaded correctly?
   Should composer regenerate its autoload cache?
6. It's not usual to have that class_exists there in magento 2 if you have a proper autoload in place. I don't think class_exists uses the current namespace so it wouldn't work anyway?

Let me know if this helped you find the answer so I can turn this into a more specific answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Arnout V, but the problem still persists. Point **5** This is my current file structure on my IDE [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qejLddXV-uHO-LmWlTCupnVyQ29Yhj-h/view?usp=sharing](File structure). I have ran the module:enable & status command successfully and everything seems to be well except for the setup:di:compile command - [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NgruHzOIDte6qEg-5WRXY8278ZhHLK8n/view?usp=sharing](error response).

Comment: Hey @Arnout, I have finally found out what was causing the issue, I have to move the Model directory inside the second dir to the root dir and made some edits to the pluginListGenerator file with the help of [https://mage2.pro/t/topic/6178] by Dmitry Fedyuk. Thanks for the direction, really appreciated it.